# React setState doesn't re render element

Tags: reactjs

I have some problems re rendering a react parent element when clicking on a child button, i'm pretty sure i've done everything to have the good context for my re rendering but it's still not working.
The process that i am making is : fetching datas from API, then render it in a chartjs, and when I click on my child button, it's setting a scope (day,week,month,quarter) that is used when refecthing datas.

Here is my parent component :

```
class ExecutiveCharts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activityEngagementData: {}
    };
    this.getChartsData = this.getChartsData.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getChartsData();
  }

  getChartsData(scope) {
    if (scope) {
      fetch("/state", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: 'userParams={"scope":"' + scope + '"}',
        credentials: "same-origin"
      });
    }

    fetch("/stats/executive/totals", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // ...
        this.setState({
          activityEngagementData: {
            // ...
          }
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(this.state.activityEngagementData)) {
      return [
        <div key="1" className="col-12 my-3 text-right">
          <ScopeButtons getChartsData={this.getChartsData.bind(this)} />
        </div>,
        <div key="2" className="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-3">
          <LineChart
            title="Activity & Engagement scores inside your community"
            chartData={this.state.activityEngagementData}
          />
        </div>
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        <div key="1" className="col-12 my-3 text-center">
          DATA IS LOADING
        </div>
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

My buttons element :

```
class ScopeButtons extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return [
      <Button
        key="1"
        className="ml-4"
        variant="raised"
        color="default"
        onClick={() => this.props.getChartsData("day")}
      >
        Day
      </Button>,
      <Button
        key="2"
        className="ml-4"
        variant="raised"
        color="default"
        onClick={() => this.props.getChartsData("week")}
      >
        Week
      </Button>,
      <Button
        key="3"
        className="ml-4"
        variant="raised"
        color="default"
        onClick={() => this.props.getChartsData("month")}
      >
        Month
      </Button>,
      <Button
        key="4"
        className="mx-4"
        variant="raised"
        color="default"
        onClick={() => this.props.getChartsData("quarter")}
      >
        Quarter
      </Button>
    ];
  }
}
```

And here is my chart component :

```
class LineChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: props.chartData
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Line
        data={this.state.chartData}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          title: {
            display: "true",
            text: this.props.title,
            fontSize: 18
          },
          tooltips: {
            mode: "label",
            intersect: false
          },
          hover: {
            mode: "label"
          },
          legend: {
            display: "true",
            position: "bottom"
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm turning around there, thank you in advance !

Comment: There's a possible race condition in `getChartsData`, as you don't wait for the first `fetch()` to complete before shooting off the other.

Comment: I did a callback to be sure that the first `fetch()` is completed, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<LineChart/>` component, you set the state equal to the props in the constructor. Why? This means only when the component is mounted will it take into account its props. When the `<LineChart/>` component gets new props, it will re-render, but it won't call its constructor again. So the state won't change, hence the `<Line/>` won't get new data. Don't set the state equal to the props in the constructor and change

```
<Line data={this.state.chartData} ... />
```

to

```
<Line data={this.props.chartData} ... />
```

That way, when new data is passed to the component, it will re-render the `<Line/>` component with that data.

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't remember that constructor wasnt called again when it was re-rendered ! I was thinking about a problem with the fetch async/sync but you solved my problem, thank you again !

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as correct if it fixed your issue, so the question can be resolved :)